# Transfer ownership of storage in Splint

Tags: c, ownership, splint

Using a simple linked list implementation in C, how do I tell Splint that I am transfer ownership of `data`?

```
typedef struct {
    void* data;
    /*@null@*/ void* next;
} list;

static /*@null@*/ list* new_list(/*@notnull@*/ void* data)
{
    list* l;

    l = malloc(sizeof(list));

    if (l == NULL)
        return NULL;

    l->next = NULL;
    l->data = data;

    return l;
}
```

I get this error message:

```
Implicitly temp storage data assigned to implicitly
                             only: list->data = data
  Temp storage (associated with a formal parameter) is transferred to a
  non-temporary reference. The storage may be released or new aliases created.
  (Use -temptrans to inhibit warning)
```

I want to tell Splint that responsibility of freeing `data` is transfered to the list data-structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in the Splint manual for [function interfaces](http://www.splint.org/manual/html/sec7.html). Basically, change the function signature to this:

```
static /*@null@*/ list* new_list(/*@notnull@*/ /*@only@*/ void* data)
    /*@defines result->data @*/
```

Although we'll get a new error when doing this:

```
int main()
{
    list* l = new_list("hej");

    return 0;
}


 Observer storage passed as only param:
                              new_list ("hej")
  Observer storage is transferred to a non-observer reference. (Use
  -observertrans to inhibit warning)
```